# Twitter API for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I want to integrate my app with twitter. I need to show tweets containing certain hashtags or from a particular user.

I tried  `MGTwitterEngine+xOAuth`, but i want twitter tweets only so no need of authentication required. `MGTwitterEngine+xOAuth` needs authentication so any API or method to get tweets certain hashtags or from a particular user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right, you don't neeed xOAth to make a search according to [twitter search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search). 
If you want to use MGTwitterEngine you can use one of those methods :

```
// Search method

- (NSString *)getSearchResultsForQuery:(NSString *)query;
- (NSString *)getSearchResultsForQuery:(NSString *)query sinceID:(MGTwitterEngineID)sinceID startingAtPage:(int)pageNum count:(int)count; // search
- (NSString *)getSearchResultsForQuery:(NSString *)query sinceID:(MGTwitterEngineID)sinceID startingAtPage:(int)pageNum count:(int)count geocode:(NSString *)geocode;
```

You can find more details in  MGTwitterEngine.h. It seems that you don't have to set authentification parameters to make a search, you just have to create an engine :

twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

Answer (score 0):

You can use MGTwitterEngine with search api or you can call [twitter search API directly](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). The problems with search API is that you can only get tweets up to 14 days old. It can be as easy as: [http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hello](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#hello)

Comment: thank you for your fast response ,my doubt is,is it possible to use mgtwitter engine without authentication?

Comment: how to find tweets up to one month old ?  any query formation required for that ?